Is signalR-2.3.0 is Content Security Policy (CSP) compatible or not?
I'm using signalR 2.3.0 version for project.
I've added this lines of code in web.config
<httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
          <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="script-src 'self' http: https: 'unsafe-inline';"/>
     </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>

I removed the unsafe-eval, will it work properly?
Like it'll work fine without give the errors or not?
I just wanna be sure that it'll work proper.
In my jquery.signalR-2.3.0.js file there is multiple setTimeout,setInterval but in one setTimeout function the call is not reaching that particular setTimeout function and I can't say it's working fine without checking it, so I just wanna know that it's (signalR [2.3.0 version]) is CSP compatible or not...
